# Mostrar contenido de una tabla MySQL en un formulario como opciones

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

buen día. Tengo una tabla que tiene dos campos, numero_genero y descripcion. No encuentro la forma de mostrar el contenido de la tabla en un formulario mediante la opcion select. Como vendría a ser ?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: necesitamos que agreges un ejemplo y donde exactamente tienes el error

Answer (score 1):

de manera simple aqui te dejo un ejemplo..si nos das un ejemplo de tu codigo te podria ayudar un poco mas saludos

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <select name="nombreSelect">
   <option value="int_valor"><?php $valor ?></option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```